# How to make a button greyed out FOREVER in MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

What I am trying to accomplish is this:
Make a button for End Time which greys out once it is clicked. When moving to a new or the next record the button appears not greyed out, but will grey out once clicked. However, when I move to the new record, the button previously clicked in the previous records appear once again. Below is my code for the on-click function of the button:

```
Private Sub Command28_Click()
txtEndTime = Time()
Command28.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

I have also written this code for the Form_Current function:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
    If Me.NewRecord Then
        Me.Command28.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```vb
Private Sub Form_Current()
    Me!Command28.Enabled = Me.NewRecord
End Sub
```

And do rename it to something meaningful.

Comment: Hi Gustav, thank you for your answer. However, the same thing happens. Whenever a new record is being created, all the buttons from previous records also become enabled.

Comment: Oh, its a continuous form. Then you can't do this; all buttons will appear the same. Move the button to the form header or footer.

Comment: Oh I see, I didn't know since I'm quite new to VBA. I tried it and it works perfectly now. Thank you so much!